# Left and right square brackets treated differently by sed/bash

Tags: bash, shell, sed, quoting

I have a file with the following contents:

```
[root@server list]# cat filenames.txt
[AAA','ACMEDEMO2','ACMEDEMO3','ACMEDEMO4','RENTCOGH','TESTENT','DORASINE','LOKAWINK','BBB]
[root@qa4app01 list]#
```

I want this as a list to use in my python script, so I am trying to change `AAA'` to `'AAA'`and `'BBB` to `'BBB'` and I thought I would use `sed` and replace `[` with `['` and `]` with `']` .

To confirm, I tried this:

```
[root@server list]# cat filenames.txt | sed "s/]/']/g"
[AAA','ACMEDEMO2','ACMEDEMO3','ACMEDEMO4','MENSCOGH','TESTENT','DORASINE','LOKAWINK','BBB']
[root@server list]#
```

It worked and I was able to replace the `]` with a `']`. So, for `AAA` I just need to change replace right square brackets and the single quote in the sed with a left square bracket and tried this:

```
[root@server list]# cat filenames.txt | sed -e "s/]/']/g" -e "s/[/['/g"
sed: -e expression #2, char 8: unterminated `s' command
[root@server list]#
```

Okay. I thought for some reason appending `sed` commands are not working properly and to check this I tried the `sed` on the left square bracket separately:

```
[root@server list]# cat filenames.txt | sed  "s/[/['/g"
sed: -e expression #1, char 8: unterminated `s' command
[root@server list]#
```

Strange. It looks as if `sed` is treating left and square brackets differently. I was able to get away without escaping the `[`, while `sed` refuses to work with `]` without the an escape character. I eventually got what I want with adding escape characters to the left square bracket like below:

`[root@server list]#  cat filenames.txt | sed -e "s/]/']/g" -e "s/\[/\['/g"
['AAA','ACMEDEMO2','ACMEDEMO3','ACMEDEMO4','MENSCOGH','TESTENT','DORASINE','LOKAWINK','BBB']
[root@server list]#`

I am in the process of writing a python + shell script which will be handling files with numerous instances of both the square brackets. My question is whether the right and left square brackets are treated differently by `sed` or `bash`.

sed version is GNU sed version 4.2.1.

P.S.: I have decided to use escape characters with both the brackets to play safe, but want to be absolutely sure it won't break the script if I don't use the escape character (for readability reasons) at places where I will be working only with right square bracket `]`

Comment: Don't use code highlighting for random English words. By the way, `\ ` is called backslash.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`[` introduces a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) and `]` closes it.

If sed sees only `]` (i.e. the closing command), it will be OK, sed assumes this is not special command.

Using only `[` (without a closing `]`) confuses `sed`, so it must be escaped.

On a side note, there is no need for

- `g` (global) flag (only one substitution per line)
- escape `[` in replacement.

I managed your change with

```
sed -e "s/]/']/" -e "s/\[/['/"
```

Comment: This "special command" is a Regular Expression _character class_ also called a _character set_. [This article](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) looks like a good intro. Or see the man page for `grep` on your system.

Answer (score 1):

Archemar explained why this failed on `[`, here's another way of making this particular replacement:

```
$ sed "s/^./['/;s/.$/']/" file
['AAA','ACMEDEMO2','ACMEDEMO3','ACMEDEMO4','RENTCOGH','TESTENT','DORASINE','LOKAWINK','BBB']
```

Or, using `&` which means "whatever you just matched":

```
$ sed "s/^./&'/;s/.$/'&/" file
['AAA','ACMEDEMO2','ACMEDEMO3','ACMEDEMO4','RENTCOGH','TESTENT','DORASINE','LOKAWINK','BBB']
```