# Removing the special character "[" using sed

Tags: sed

I have string "[9920380315,POSTPAID,0009,646.26,SELF,APPLICATION]"

in that I want to remove first "[" but unable to do this using  below command,

```
sed 's/[//g'
```

Comment: `tr -d '['` (assuming a POSIX `tr`).

Comment: Where is this string stored? In a variable or in a text file?

Answer (score 5):

Try doing this :

```
sed 's/\[//'
```

The `[ ]` are special metacharacters used to match a character from a set (like `[a-z]`).

Comment: On another note, you will be able to replace `[` without the escape character :)

Comment: No Sree: `sed: -e expression #1, char 5: unterminated `s' command`

Comment: @sputnick I think that error came from an unterminated `s`. I had asked a question here a few days back http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/168240/left-and-right-square-brackets-treated-differently-by-sed-bash

Comment: @Sree As the answer to your question explains, you can't use an unescaped `[`

Answer (score 2):

```
start cmd:> echo "[9920380315,POSTPAID,0009,646.26,SELF,APPLICATION]" |
  sed 's/[[]//'
9920380315,POSTPAID,0009,646.26,SELF,APPLICATION]
```

Answer (score 2):

or directly with bash

```
code="[9920380315,POSTPAID,0009,646.26,SELF,APPLICATION]"
echo "${code/[/}"
```

Comment: Unlike OP's `sed`command, this will only remove the first occurrence of `[`, use `//`

Comment: yep but that was the request, remove the first [ of the string

Comment: sure, but it may be worth mentioning at least ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This would help you,

```
$ echo '[9920380315,POSTPAID,0009,646.26,SELF,APPLICATION]'|sed 's/^\[//'
9920380315,POSTPAID,0009,646.26,SELF,APPLICATION]
```

Answer (score 0):

I got a single pass to work to remove both `[` AND `]` using a combined `sed` expression which I had not considered before with 2 expressions separated with a semicolon :

```
$ echo "ON bec.[BusinessID] = s.[BusinessID]" | sed 's/\[//g; s/\]//g'
ON bec.BusinessID = s.BusinessID
```

Comment: More efficiently done with `tr -d '[]'`. Also note that the request was for removing the _first_ `[` only.

Comment: This can be done more concisely (although less clearly) with `sed 's/[][]//g'`, which was already given as an answer.  Also, FYI, you can do `s/]//` without escaping the `]`.

Answer (score -1):

or

```
$ echo "[HTML],[FLASK]"|sed 's/[][]//g'
HTML,FLASK
```

Comment: This removes more than the first `[`.